# How to Install rails on Elementary O.S.?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What exactly *is* Elementary O.S. ? Rails provides support for UBUNTU,LINUX,WINDOWS,MAC but there is no mention of ELEMENTARY. Is it advisable to try rails on my existing system?

I am using Elementary OS : Version: 0.2 "Luna" (64-bit).

How do I install Rails on it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Elementary OS](http://elementary.io) is a debian based linux distribution. If you are familiar with Ubuntu, all the knowledge is easily portable. Installing Rails is not as different in ElementaryOS from what you do in Ubuntu.

To start, find Terminal program from Applications menu and start it.

[rvm](http://rvm.io) is probably the best option for installing Ruby:

```
# installing rvm
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm

# installing ruby 2.2.3
rvm install 2.2.3
ruby --version
```

With ruby in place you can now intstall Rails:

```
gem install rails
```

Comment: Thank you ob@ob-Satellite-C660:~$ rails -v
Rails 2.3.14
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: @kinley619 do you ask me something?

Comment: Thank you. I am sorry  I am new to this whole thing. Hope you understand :)                                                                                                   I am still unable to use it . The 'new' command doesn't work. eg. rails new myapp   creates a an app called NEW. Also when I run 'rails server' command it creates an app called SERVER
rails -v ...Rails 2.3.14
ruby -v   ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: rails -v gives `2.3.14`? It's too old! Is there any reason to learn such an old release?

Comment: I followed a tutorial before reading your comment .. sorry hehe . Is there some way I can update it ?

Comment: Do you have rvm installed?

Comment: rvm -v gives me    .....     rvm 1.26.11 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

Comment: First of all install newer version of ruby. `rvm install 2.2.3`

Comment: This is what I am getting ....Thank you so much ,mate :)                                                                        Already installed ruby-2.2.3.
To reinstall use:

    rvm reinstall ruby-2.2.3

Comment: and then `gem install rails` it will install the latest version of `rails`

Comment: Thank you Dimitri .I reinstalled it.It worked . Can you please tell me the difference between terminal that is reached by "ctrl+alt+t" and the one that is reached by typing  "gnome-terminal"..? the latter seems to work better for some reason

Comment: PS: THANK YOU ...I HOPE TO BE LIKE YOU SOME DAY ! *CHEERS*

Comment: @kinley619 I'm not sure I know the difference between them. Better ask it at AskUbuntu. Thanks for your words :) And happy coding